# How to use Ladda UI for Bootstrap 3

Tags: jsp, servlets, twitter-bootstrap-3

I am a little bit confused about "Ladda UI for Bootstrap 3" which merges loading indicators into the action that invoked them. When I click the button, it will execute a SQL query. So, how can I stop spin effect whenever query is done? I use jsp and servlets.

Answer (score -1):

see: http://msurguy.github.io/ladda-bootstrap/ for documentation.

```
$(function() {
    $('#form-submit').click(function(e){
        e.preventDefault();
        var l = Ladda.create(this);
        l.start();
        $.post("your-url", 
            { data : data },
          function(response){
            console.log(response);
          }, "json")
        .always(function() { l.stop(); });
        return false;
    });
});
```

here `your-url` should be a URL which preform your sql, the result of this url should be:

```
The type of data that you're expecting back from the server. If none is specified, jQuery will try to infer it based on the MIME type of the response (an XML MIME type will yield XML, in 1.4 JSON will yield a JavaScript object, in 1.4 script will execute the script, and anything else will be returned as a string). The available types (and the result passed as the first argument to your success callback) are: xml, html, json, jsonp or text
```

Now you can call `l.stop` based on your response data or ajax request;

```
// Assign handlers immediately after making the request,
// and remember the jqxhr object for this request
var jqxhr = $.post( "example.php", function() {
  alert( "success" );
})
  .done(function() {
    alert( "second success" );
  })
  .fail(function() {
    alert( "error" );
  })
  .always(function() {
    alert( "finished" );
});
```